# how to implement a REST-client with tomee and CXF using MultivaluedMap?

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, apache-tomee

I'm not able to find the right dependency to implement a REST client with tomEE and CXF.

My module has this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomee-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The initial client implementation is simple. It has to serve a post method and submit a MultiValueMap.

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.form.Form;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    public class RestClient<T> {

        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestClient.class);
        private WebClient client;
        private Class<T> type;

        public RestClient(Class<T> aType, String aBaseUrl, String aPath) {

            this.client = WebClient.create(aBaseUrl);
            this.client.path(aPath);
            this.client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            this.type = aType;
        }

        public T post(MultivaluedMap<String, String> params) {

            LOG.debug("sending POST request to: " + this.client.getCurrentURI());
            Form theForm = new Form(params);
            T theReponse = (T) this.client.post(theForm, this.type.getClass());
            return theReponse;
        }   
    }
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out an implementation of javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap. In result I cannot call my method. :(
I see only the interface. Isn't CXF completely provided by my pom.xml and doesn't it have an implementation of this interface? What dependency should I use to enable a proper work of CXF with tomEE?

I did not find any example on the web.

Answer (score 0):

With cxf, the `MultivaluedMap` implementation is [`org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.MetadataMap`](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/impl/MetadataMap.html).

In newer JAX-RS 2.0 compliant versions, there is a [`javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedHashMap.html), but with JAX-RS 1.x, the implementation of the interface is implementation specific.

Comment: thank you! That helped. Anymway now the marshaling from json to T does not work, but this is a different problem.